# BBC football webscraping issue

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape this page for the table data:

https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/premier-league/table

But what I end up with is a different section of the webpage

```
table_MN = pd.read_html('https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/premier-league/table')
print(f'Total tables: {len(table_MN)}')
df=table_MN
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you expect, but `pandas.read_html()` works fine for the "raw HTML". Only some of the elements like the name of the team are morphed by the script and will not appear in your result.

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.read_html('https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/premier-league/table')[0]
```

If you want to get rid of the last row you can slice your data frame with  `iloc[:-1]`

```
df.iloc[:-1]#.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

**Note** *If you like to get specific information like the title of the `<abbr>` that holds the full team name scrape the table with bs4 directly. *

#### Output

| Unnamed: 0 | Unnamed: 1 | Team | P | W | D | L | F | A | GD | Pts | Form |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | team hasn't moved | Man City | 25 | 20 | 3 | 2 | 61 | 14 | 47 | 63 | WWon 2 - 1 against Arsenal on January 1st 2022.WWon 1 - 0 against Chelsea on January 15th 2022.DDrew 1 - 1 against Southampton on January 22nd 2022.WWon 2 - 0 against Brentford on February 9th 2022.WWon 4 - 0 against Norwich City on February 12th 2022. |
| 2 | team hasn't moved | Liverpool | 24 | 16 | 6 | 2 | 61 | 19 | 42 | 54 | DDrew 2 - 2 against Chelsea on January 2nd 2022.WWon 3 - 0 against Brentford on January 16th 2022.WWon 3 - 1 against Crystal Palace on January 23rd 2022.WWon 2 - 0 against Leicester City on February 10th 2022.WWon 1 - 0 against Burnley on February 13th 2022. |
| 3 | team hasn't moved | Chelsea | 24 | 13 | 8 | 3 | 48 | 18 | 30 | 47 | DDrew 1 - 1 against Brighton & Hove Albion on December 29th 2021.DDrew 2 - 2 against Liverpool on January 2nd 2022.LLost 0 - 1 against Manchester City on January 15th 2022.DDrew 1 - 1 against Brighton & Hove Albion on January 18th 2022.WWon 2 - 0 against Tottenham Hotspur on January 23rd 2022. |

Comment: Ok, so I was being dumb and realised it had scraped it all, just not displaying nicely.

So how do I get it to display nicely like you did?

Comment: Display the data frame by just calling `df` or export it to another format `df.iloc[:-1].to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)` - Hope this will answer your question.